# External database doens't work

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

Here is my code and it shows error:

```
'no such table:AddressBookGroup:,While compiling select * from AddressBookGroup'
```

I Have put db file in asstes folder with this table.

I have used openhelper class code from this link [using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class AddressBookGroup {
    private final static String ID = "ID";
    private final static String NAME = "Name";

    public String Id;
    public String Name;

    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.devindia.dataSample/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AirtelApp.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "AddressBookGroup";

    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public AddressBookGroup(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        OpenHelper oh=new OpenHelper(context);
        try {
            oh.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    this.db=    oh.openDataBase();
        int i=0;



    }

    public AddressBookGroup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void insert(AddressBookGroup ret) {
        final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        values.put(ID, cursor.getCount() + 1);
        values.put(NAME, ret.Name);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    }

    public AddressBookGroup[] selectAll() {

        // Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { NAME },
        // null,null, null, null, "name desc");
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);

        AddressBookGroup[] ret = new AddressBookGroup[cursor.getCount()];
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int i = 0;
            do {
                ret[i] = new AddressBookGroup();
                ret[i].Id = (cursor.getString(0));
                ret[i].Name = (cursor.getString(1));
                    // ret[i].Name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NAME));
                // ret[i].Name= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PHONE));
                i++;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        Context context;

        OpenHelper(Context context) {

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }

        /**
         * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
         * database.
         * */
        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if (dbExist) {
                // do nothing - database already exist
            } else {

                // By calling this method and empty database will be created
                // into the default system path
                // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
                // database with our database.
                this.getReadableDatabase();

                try {

                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                }
            }

        }

        /**
         * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
         * time you open the application.
         * 
         * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
         */
        private boolean checkDataBase() {

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try {
                String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {

                // database does't exist yet.

            }

            if (checkDB != null) {

                checkDB.close();

            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

            // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[3072];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

        public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
            SQLiteDatabase db1;
            // Open the database
            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            db1 = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            int i = 0;
            return db1;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First copy your database in asset folder. And try to implements following code .

public static void copyDataBase()
    {
        try
          {
                   //Open your local db as the input stream

```
              OutputStream databaseOutputStream = new
              FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.devindia.dataSample/databases");
           // Path to the just created empty db


            InputStream databaseInputStream;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        databaseInputStream = minnesota.databaseInputStream1;


        while ( (length = databaseInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            databaseOutputStream.write(buffer);
        }
        databaseInputStream.close();

        databaseInputStream = minnesota.databaseInputStream2;

        while ( (length = databaseInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            databaseOutputStream.write(buffer);
        }
        databaseInputStream .close();        
        databaseOutputStream.flush();
        databaseOutputStream.close();



      }catch (Exception e) {
                       // TODO: handle exception
              //Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
}
```

Comment: This code works fine for me and i hope that will also for U .